# How to check if a submit button has already been clicked in PHP

Tags: php, button, submit, click

I basically have an updatecart.php script which INSERTS data into a database table once the submit button from the HTML page has been clicked, it then goes to display.php where the updated content is shown. The problem I have is that I have a quantity field in my displayed data and if the user clicks the submit button (add stuff to shopping cart) then I want the quantity to increase by how much quantity the user has chosen in in the dropdown menu in the HTML page. Right now if the user clicks the submit button again nothing happens as it is the same data being added to the database table.

Code:

HTML:

```
<form name = "AddToCart" action ="../updatecart.php" method='post'>
  Quantity:
  <select name="Quantity">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  </select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type ="submit" name ="Add" value="Add To Cart"/>
  </form>
```

updatecart.php:

```
<?php

// Connection to database omitted 

$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Cart VALUES
('1', 'The Fiqh of Dawah', '18.00', 'Books', '$Quantity')";
mysql_query($query);

header("location:displaycart.php");

?>
```

display.php:

```
//Not necessary to show this as it simply uses `echo` to create a table and display the whole table data with `SELECT * FROM Cart`
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` library. It has been deprecated. `mysqli` is the replacement. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Be careful: your code is not safe ! It can be hacked with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the item already exists in the cart by doing a `SELECT` first, and then choose between an `INSERT` (if no rows exists for this item in the cart) or an `UPDATE` (if this item is already in the cart).

In MySql, You can also do it by using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). But You will need to have a primary key to do so.

Comment: Thankyou @Eric Citaire, the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is what I needed and its worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isset($_POST['Add'])` to check the submit button submitted or not

like

```
if(isset($_POST['Add']))
{
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Cart VALUES
('1', 'The Fiqh of Dawah', '18.00', 'Books', '$Quantity')";
mysql_query($query);

header("location:displaycart.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check in your updatecart.php at the top to check if Submit has been clicked.

Something like

```
isset($_POST['Add']) {
// insert data into DB
}
else {
// redirect somewhere as they havent clicked Submit button
}
```

You should also be running your user data through a check/sanitize before you input into your DB.